# jQuery mobile link transitioning to a leaflet map

Tags: jquery-mobile, leaflet

I have a site using jQuery Mobile, and one of the pages shows a map using Cloudmade's Leaflet.

[This page loads up and shows a map with a marker](http://placr.mobi/map?lat=51.45289&lon=-0.1003&zoom=16), and this all works fine but...

[I have another page with a link to the map page](http://placr.mobi/maplinktest), then this loads up OK apart from it seems to try to get the marker image file from the wrong place.

**Can anyone tell me more about what's going wrong on that page?**

Here what I know. jQuery Mobile does rewriting of plain A HREF links to do ajax dynamic loading of the destination page instead. This is mysterious and unfathomable to me, but mostly a developer like me shouldn't need to concern myself with it right?  However in this case something about the leaflet invocation code is not surviving the mangling.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://placr.mobi/dist/images/marker.png
```

...is the error reported by safari. Indeed this path is incorrect. I set it up leaflet with the contents of the 'dist' directory placed in a directory called 'leaflet'. Should work? In fact it *does* work apart from after the jQuery mangling.

Investigating a little, I found no mention of 'dist' in the leaflet source code (as I would expect. I should be able to call that directory something else surely?) but a reference *does* get compiled into a the uglified javascript ('`return"../../dist/"`')

Maybe someone has an example of jQuery Mobile and leaflet working together (ideally including marker image)

Comment: tried to place rel="external" to your link? 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned below, rel="external" is not ideal, but it's actually the fix I've gone for in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the leaflet.js evaluates the ROOT_URL based on the script tag's src attribute in the html. But the script tag is missing from your first page.

In your first page (http://placr.mobi/maplinktest) put the above line:

```
<script src="/leaflet/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

exactly under the:

```
<div data-role="content" >
```

A second alternative solution is to add the following in your second page:

```
L.Icon = L.Icon.extend({
    iconUrl: <markerUrl>,
    shadowUrl: <shadowUrl>
});
```

With the second way you are explicitly setting the image URLs.

A third solution is to add rel="external" in the first page's anchor:

```
<a href="/map?lat=51.45289&amp;lon=-0.1003&amp;zoom=16" rel="external" class="ui-link">Link to map page</a>
```

Comment: You're right! On my test server I see that fixes the problem. The marker image now loads! I guess I could run with this solution but it just has the slight disadvantage of loading leaflet in places where it's not needed. So that same leaflet script tag is included on the destination page content section which gets loaded in by ajax.  I wander if there's a way of getting this evaluating of the ROOT_URL to happen on that dynamically loaded script tag

Comment: I added a second alternative solution in my post.

Comment: I added a third alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks. The second alternative fixed it a little bit, but it still seemed to run into the same image url problem after following several (ajaxy) links in the navigation structure of my site. Or occasionally the map failed to load at all. Alternative three certainly nails the problem by doing a conventional page reload. Seems slightly clumsy because again it involves changes elsewhere on the site, also I no longer enjoy those funky transition effects. ...but it'll do.  Thanks for your help